# I2C scanner is not Detecting any device on Arduino Due Board

Tags: c++, arduino

I2C scanner is not Detecting any device on Arduino Due Board.
It always giving result as `Found 0 device(s)`.

Comment: This sounds like it may be a hardware issue rather than programming. Can you add more information about your setup, what you're trying to do, and what you've tried already?

Comment: I'm currently having the same issue with the Due. I'm nearly positive it isn't hardware since the device is working fine. I'm using a HMC5883L breakout board from Sparkfun.

Comment: That's what..when i am working with atmel studio it is working fine but when i am working with due for same hardware there is no output.